# How could I create a transition effect similar to the "start voting" button on this website?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a transition effect on hover that is similar to the large "start voting" button on [this website](https://vote.webbyawards.com/PublicVoting#/2020/websites/general-websites/community) but, while I am familiar with css transition effects, I dont know how to create that one in particular. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a background-size transition:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 80px;
  border: 2px solid #BDAA67;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#BDAA67, #BDAA67);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 0%;
  transition: background-size .3s, color .3s;
}
a:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">
    CLICK ME!
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{content: "";
background-color: #bdaa67;
height: 0%;
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
left: 25%;
transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
top: 48%;
z-index: -1;}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines of code to your HTML,

```
<button class="custom-btn">Start now</button>
```

Add the following lines of code to your custom.css. This will give the exact style on hover for the button. You can minimise the code if you are willing to use bootstrap. Here we have custom styled the button from scratch.

```
.custom-btn {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 32px 105px;
  text-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
}

.custom-btn:hover {
  border: 2px solid #bdaa67;
  color: #000;
}

.custom-btn::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #bdaa67;
  height: 0%;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
  top: 48%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.custom-btn:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <button> START VOTING </button>
</body>

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
}


button {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 40px 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1;
}

button::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #bdaa67;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

button:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1);
}

button:hover {
  border: 3px solid #bdaa67;
  color: #000;
}
```